# Image preview in ruby on rails using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So i'm building an image previewer during upload in my rails app and  I stumbled upon [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158176/how-to-display-a-tempfile-image-in-views-with-rails-active-storage). If I understand it right, there's an onchange listener in the file input and it triggers to change the src of an image tag to the  URL of the uploaded file. Here's my version:

```
function readURL(input) {
    console.log(input.files)
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {     
        var reader = new FileReader();          
        
        reader.onload = function(e) {       
            let imagePreviewContainer = document.getElementById('image-preview-container');
            let previewContent = "";
        
            for (let i = 0; i < e.target.result.length; i++) {
                previewContent += `<img src="${e.target.result[i]}">`
            }
        console.log(previewContent);
        imagePreviewContainer.innerHTML = previewContent;
      }
       
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string   
    } 
}

let imageFileField = document.getElementById('image-input');
imageFileField.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log("upload detected");   
    console.log(this);
    readURL(this);
});
```

here's the .html.erb file:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="create-item-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="create-item-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="create-item-modalLabel">New listing</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= form_with scope: :item, url: items_path(current_user.id), local: true do |f| %>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :name, "Item name" %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", autofocus: true %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :images %><br />
                <%= f.file_field :images, id: "image-input", multiple: true %>
              </div>

              <div id="image-preview-contaier"></div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :description %><br />
                <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control", size: "30x10", autofocus: true %>
              </div>
              
              <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "open" %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag(:user_id, current_user.id) %>
            
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <%= f.submit "Create listing", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

With these modifications, I get an empty object in when I console.log(this) so the readURL function doesn't really get the correct argument. What seems to be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's better to use `URL.createOjectURL(file)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix it.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        for (let i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute("style","width:100px; height:auto;");
    
            reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                var image = new Image();
                image.width = 100;
                image.title = input.name;
                image.src = this.result;
                imagePreviewContainer.appendChild(image);
              }, false);

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]); // convert to base64 string
            
        }
    } 
}

const imagePreviewContainer = document.getElementById('image-preview-container');
const imageFileField = document.getElementById('image-input');
imageFileField.addEventListener('change', function() {  
    readURL(this);
});
```

I went to the FileReader docs and followed how to implement the load listener. Also, I changed the contents of the imagePreviewContainer being an innerHTML to dynamically create img tags using the createElement method.